# I want the actual file name that is returned by a PHP script

Tags: php, python, url, scripting

I am writing a python script that downloads a file given by a URL. Unfortuneatly the URL is in the form of a PHP script i.e. www.website.com/generatefilename.php?file=5233

If you visit the link in a browser, you are prompted to download the actual file and extension. I need to send this link to the downloader, but I can't send the downloader the PHP link.

How would I get the full file name in a usable variable?

Comment: Can you clarify?  Do you want the variable to contain "generatefilename.php"?

Comment: I want it to contain the file name returned by the php script, e.g. www.website.com/fullpath/5233Retrieved.dat

Comment: You won't be able to get a URL like `www.website.com/fullpath/5233Retrieved.dat`. It's very possible that no such URL exists. you can get the `5233Retrieved.dat` filename however from the `Content-Disposition` header sent from PHP to your Python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
urllib.urlretrieve(URL, directory + "\\" + filename + "." + extension)
```

This saved the file generated by the PHP file to the designated folder with the designated name and extension. I configured the downloader to automatically check this folder for new files, so this solution works for me.

Comment: Nevermind, the files are all the same size and don't contain the correct data!

Comment: Actually I renamed the files and found that they are webpages requiring authentication, so I don't think my script was authenticated before attempting to obtain the files. So it might work if I could just figure out how to authenticate with the website via URL, if thats possible.

Comment: Ok, with authentication, this line retrieves the generated file.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is examine the `Content-Disposition` header sent by the PHP script. it will look something like:

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=theFilenameYouWant`

As to how you actually examine that header it depends on the python code you're currently using to fetch the URL. If you post some code I'll be able to give a more detailed answer.

Comment: I am retrieving the PHP url from an RSS feed, and want to pass the file (and full path) generated by visiting the PHP URL into a variable, so that I can send it to a downloader application via a localhost url. Basically the PHP URL is given, and I have no code that handles the PHP

Comment: Are you using Python to access the PHP script via HTTP?

Comment: I'm using python to parse XML and obtain the PHP Script's URL e.g. www.website.com/generatefilename.php?file=5233 and store it in a variable. What I want is to get the URL to the file name generated by the script. I have no idea how to do this. All I have so far is this URL to a PHP Script, and I know that if I visit it in Firefox, a download dialog comes up for the generated/retrieved file  e.g. 5233Retrieved.dat and that's the file whose full path I want to store in a variable.

Comment: If you use Python to fetch the `www.website.com/generatefilename.php?file=5233` URL, you can examine the HTTP headers and they will contain the filename. To authenticate when fetching content over HTTP using Python is a separate question.